# NAA flag is declined

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flag [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437686/72456) as "Not an Answer" but it was declined.Is that really answer the question?

Note that now the post is deleted but I want to know if I did or use wrong flag or if I was not wrong then why it's rejected because that's the only one of those posts I spending my time to read the question and then read the answer posted and decide it doesn't answer to the question and flag it.

Comment: Without knowing the flag activity, this may help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/307535

Answer (score 5):

That one got flagged several times, and I don't really understand why, so maybe I'm the one missing it. The question was how to delete a file with special characters in it, and the answer was to move it into an empty directory and delete the directory. That would work as far as I can tell, although Kusalananda raised a good point in the comments that you'd probably run into the same difficulty moving the file that you had removing it.

All the flags/comments were of the opinion the answer didn't address the question; one even asked if the author had mixed up which question they had answered. It was definitely an answer to that question, but probably not a very helpful one since you'd run into the same issue trying to move the file.

Comment: I was read the same before flagging but in this way "move other files you know thier name to another directory then delete the directory with weird files name in" which this may or may not the one OP already stated in his question as a alternative solution, but really that answer doesn't answer to the question. maybe if I left a comment it was not declined, thanks in advance for the feedback

Comment: @αғsнιη Oh! You're right, I didn't notice that the asker had already suggested that option. That does make it not an answer, my mistake